# Asymptotic pseudo orbit of an action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be finitely generated group (i.e $G= \langle S\rangle$, $S=\{s_1, ...,s_n\}$) and  $\varphi:G\times M\longrightarrow M$ an action. Then $f:G\longrightarrow M$ is called $\delta$-*pseudo orbit* if $d(f(sg), \varphi(s,f(g)))<\delta$ for every $s\in S$, $g\in G$. How can we define an asymptotic pseudo orbit for action $\varphi:G\times M\longrightarrow M$?

Comment: Let $M$ be a compact manifold, In $(M, g)$,  $\{x_n\}\subseteq M$ is
an asymptotic pseudo orbit if $d(g(x_n), x_{n+1})\longrightarrow 0$
as $|n|\longrightarrow \infty$.